# Git development without clone

Tags: git

I am new to git and I am familiar with the regular git clone, develop, commit, push workflow. In one of the tutorials I watched, I noticed the developer doing the following:

```
git init
git fetch ssh://someserver.git refs/data/val
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
.
. make changes to files
.
git commit -am "somemessage"
git push ssh://someserver.git HEAD:refs/data/val
```

Could someone help to explain:

1. What workflow is being followed here? What could be the reason of doing this without cloning?
2. What is the meaning of `refs/data/val` in the `git fetch` command?

NOTE: This is not to understand what FETCH_HEAD is. So it is not a duplicate.

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fetch only one branch of a remote git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a weird workflow, and not really useful in general. Its main feature is using a peculiar reference namespace, treating `refs/data/val` as if it were a branch name.

The effect is *like* cloning with `--single-branch`, except that instead he clones with *no* branch, then treats the funny ref as if it were a branch.

The `git checkout` step produces a detached HEAD.

The subsequent commit makes a new commit that extends the detached HEAD.

The final `git push` updates the other Git, continuing to treat the peculiarly named reference as a branch.  The other Git is free to reject the push.  Many/most would do simply because `refs/data/` is not a known-to-be-safe namespace for pushes.

Since there is no named remote, the remote's branch-names cannot be stored locally for convenience in merging and/or rebasing.  Since there are no named branches, Git's built-in branch behavior cannot be used for convenience in committing, merging, and/or rebasing.  Since there are neither named branches, nor a named remote, Git's built-in `push` behavior cannot be used, requiring the fully-spelled-out URL and `HEAD`-to-ref push.

In short, this is an inconvenient way to use Git unconventionally.

Answer (score 1):

This might provide some insight for the overall workflow:
[What is the difference between pull and clone in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620633/what-is-the-difference-between-pull-and-clone-in-git)

As for the second question, he was fetching the *branch* `refs/data/val` from the repo at his *.git link.

Comment: I think `refs/data/val` is a branch, AFAIK